# cta button - Parts of the url is a variable

Tags: wordpress, email-validation

I have a wordpress site with a plugin called Form maker. It sends a confirmation email to the submitters email adress after submission, in which I have a link that they have to click to confirm there submission.

This link is partly variable though. Its for example: https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/?gid=135&h=b698188169220cffc34@5

The part: https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/
is always the same, but the rest aren't.

The code for the link that's in the email template is showing in "html view" as: {verificationlink}

I would like to wrap a cta button around this link, so it looks better.

Best regards 
Nicolai

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me try.

formmaker plugin - how it looks like in wordpress

"Hi thanks for signing up bla bla.
Please click the button below to confirm

{verificationlink}

Thanks!"

What the submitters receive pr. mail:

"Hi thanks for signing up bla bla.
Please click the button below to confirm
https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/?gid=135&h=b6981881692278d1bf10cffc34@5

Thanks!"

This link i would like to show as a button instead that says "Confirm".

The part: https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/ is always the same, but the rest aren't. Every time a submitter fill in the form and press submits, the plugin creates the rest after so it becomes:
https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/?gid=135&h=b6981881692278d1bf10cffc34@5

Thanks for taking your time to help me

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<a href="{verificationlink}">Verify</a>
```

assuming {verificationlink} will echo this link "https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/?gid=135&h=b698188169220cffc34@5"

You can use css to format a tag if you are using html email

> Basic thing is you need to put your link in a href tag and format it using css

"Hi thanks for signing up bla bla. Please click the button below to confirm

{verificationlink}

Thanks!"

What the submitters receive pr. mail:

"Hi thanks for signing up bla bla. Please click the button below to confirm [Confirm](https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/?gid=135&h=b6981881692278d1bf10cffc34@5)

Thanks!"

This link i would like to show as a button instead that says "Confirm".

The part: https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/ is always the same, but the rest aren't. Every time a submitter fill in the form and press submits, the plugin creates the rest after so it becomes: https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/?gid=135&h=b6981881692278d1bf10cffc34@5

Comment: Hi Charan Thanks for your reply
I have triend similar, and just to check I insertet your code in the email, and the link i received in the mail box was this: <a href =https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/?gid=136&h=fb830425c5c6e1665b1396640489ea50@5>https://skip.dk/fmemailverification/kapsiodk-bekraeftelse/?gid=136&h=fb830425c5c6e1665b1396640489ea50@5</a><br/>